# How to get raw date string from date picker?

Tags: reactjs, date, antd, iso

I'm struggling for hours with this seemingly trivial issue.

I have a `antd` datepicker on my page.

Whenever I choose a date, instead of giving me the date I chose, it gives me a messy moment object, which I can't figure out how to read.

All I want is that when I choose "2020-01-18", it should give me precisely this string that the user chose, regardless of timezone, preferably in ISO format.

This is not a multi-national website. I just need a plain vanilla date so I can send it to the server, store in db, whatever.

Here are some of my trials, so far no luck:

```js
var fltval = e;
if (isMoment(fltval)) {
  var dat = fltval.toDate();
  //dat.setUTCHours(0)
  fltval = dat.toISOString(); // fltval.toISOString(false)

  var a = dat.toUTCString();
  //var b = dat.toLocaleString()
}
```

It keeps on moving with a few hours, probably to compensate for some timezone bias

UPDATE 1:

the `datestring` is data-wise correct. But its not ISO, so I cant use it correctly. I might try to parse this, but I cannot find a way to parse a string to date with a specific format.

UPDATE 2:

I also tried adding the bias manually, but for some reason the bias is 0

```
var dat = pickerval.toDate()
var bias = Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()// this is 0...
var bias2 = dat.getTimezoneOffset()// and this too is 0
var d2 = new Date(dat.getTime()+bias)
var mystring= dat.toISOString() //still wrong
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<DatePicker onChange={(date,dateString)=>{ console.log(dateString) }} />` is dateString what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I added an update. The date is correct. but its not usable.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript date functions can be used,

I assume you are getting in 2022-01-03T11:19:07.946Z format then

```
date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

to 2022-01-03

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Since the bias is a negative. the date itself is sometimes also wrong. i.e. if i choose 2020-10-10 00:00:00, then the picker moves it to 2020-10-09 23:00:00 :-(

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to get the date string:

1. Use the moment.format api:
   `date.format("yyyy-MM-DD")`
2. Use the date string that is passed to the onChange as second parameter

Here is a [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-18-2-forked-50y4g?file=/index.js:207-232).

Comment: Hi. Thanks. `date.format` makes the same bug. I tried `fltval.format("yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")` and got back '2021-08-02T22:00:00'. even though I chose Aug 3. Please advise.

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox, your code. Like in what way is it the wrong date.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sandbox. but I'm choosing "Aug 3 2021". so how come its giving me "2021-08-02T22:00:00"? which is offset by -2 hours. (which happens to be my browsers local timezone bias, but i dont care for tz bias at all)

Comment: The moment object will always be local time. Which is correct since that's the day they selected. You could overcome it by accessing the UTC offset and add it to the moment date or create a new momet UTC object and you fill o ly year, month and day from the selected date before turning it into UTC to get selected da.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a good idea. But for some reason the bias by me shows as 0. Please see update 2 in my post. Thanks!

Comment: Put it on the date not the prototype : dat.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Same thing. It's also 0. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your code snippet is inside the onChange method. This gives you a moment and a date string to work with (the first and second parameters of the function respectively).

You have a few options. You could set the format prop on the DatePicker to match the format of the string you want. Then just use the date string. Or you can use the moment object as Domino987 described.